# RackBeat Webhook Issue with Cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare, cdn

### When we update stock in Rackbeat, its webhook triggers, and that webhook utilizes WooCommerce REST API to POST/PATCH the stock updated into the associated/integrated website.

We are using a woocommecer plugin in our website and getting data from RackBeat through this plugin. It is working fine when we enabled the proxied for CDN on cloudflare it stopped working. We also need a CDN We tried adding some rules to the WAF but had no success. Can anyone help with this issue?

We tried to apply different rules in the WAF.

Comment: what do you mean for "stopped working"? can you provide more info - some errors, logs, etc

Comment: Actually, the integration is handled by RackBeat. We believe this is a related CDN issue, we tested it after disabling the CDN (proxy) and it works fine. Here are some error logs. 
WooCommerce Webshop
Title Error Date
Upload stock FS310 A2935-1520 to Woocommerce JSON ERROR: Syntax error 08-04-2023 14:08:30
Upload stock FS310 A2935-1520 to Woocommerce JSON ERROR: Syntax error 08-04-2023 14:08:30
Upload stock F396854-03 to Woocommerce JSON ERROR: Syntax error 08-04-2023 14:08:30
Upload stock F396854-03 to Woocommerce JSON ERROR: Syntax error 07-04-2023 07:07:12